# Animate color on loaded JSON model in three js

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, gsap

Is there a way, to animate a loaded JSON model colors in three js?

As you could see it, I used the the `ObjectLoader()` in my code and it renders the model, but after that I would like to animate the color of it.

```
        var objectLoader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
        var model;
        objectLoader.load("path/to/model.json", function ( obj ) {

            object.traverse( function ( child ) {
                if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ){

                    model = child.material.color;
                }
            });
            scene.add( obj );
        } );
```

I would like to use GSAP for the animation. So far I know that I could change the color of the `model` with `model.material.color.setRGB(1,1,1);` But is there any way, to animate it?

Answer (score 2):

I worked with GSAP not so much. I prefer to use Tween.js, which is in the distributive of Three.js and it's a small library ;)

But the conception of changin the color is the same, I think.

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 10);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

var colorStart = new THREE.Color("red");
var colorEnd = new THREE.Color("blue");

var box = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(5, 5, 10, 10), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  wireframe: true
}));
box.material.color.copy(colorStart);
scene.add(box);

var tween = new TWEEN.Tween(box.material.color).to(colorEnd, 2000).easing(TWEEN.Easing.Bounce.Out);
tween.start();


render();

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  TWEEN.update();
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/90/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/libs/tween.min.js"></script>
```

[Visualized easings](http://sole.github.io/tween.js/examples/03_graphs.html)

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this would be the three.js animation system. <s>I don't know whether it's possible with GSAP, or if GSAP is focused on HTML attribute animation? If so you might have better luck combining GSAP with an HTML-based graphics framework like A-Frame</s>.

From one of the [official examples](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=key#misc_animation_keys) —

```
var colorTrack = new THREE.ColorKeyframeTrack(
  '.material.color',
  [ 0, 1, 2 ], // keyframe times
  [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 ], // colors: r1, g1, b1, r2, g2, b2...
  THREE.InterpolateLinear
);
var clip = new THREE.AnimationClip( 'myclip', undefined, [ colorTrack ] );
mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( mesh );
var clipAction = mixer.clipAction( clip );
clipAction.play();

// in render loop
mixer.update( clock.getDelta() );
```

It is also common to use another animation library like tweenjs, which can be easier to work with depending on what you need.

three.js r90